# Как запустить jar файл (создан в NetBeans)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jvm

Есть проект на java. Собираю jar файл в NetBeans IDE 12.2.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.vit</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa-utility</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring JPA</name>

    <properties>
        <tika>1.2</tika>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tika}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>${tika}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>${tika}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.vit.TikaSample</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
   
</project>
```

Если запускать через NetBeans, то проект работает и выполняется. Собираю через maven. Если запускать через консоль командой:

```
java -jar D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\Unit1\apache-tika\target\spring-jpa-utility-1.0.jar
```

то выводится ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом, если запускать jar файл двойным кликом, то появляется такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал запускать jar файл через javaw.exe и java.exe, результат один и тот же, не работает.

Вот мой файл manifest:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: РўР°С‚СЊСЏРЅР° (тут имя учетной записи Татьяна, поэтому так выводит)
Class-Path: tika-core-1.2.jar tika-parsers-1.2.jar vorbis-java-tika-0.
1.jar netcdf-4.2-min.jar apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar apache-mime4j-d
om-0.7.2.jar commons-compress-1.4.1.jar xz-1.0.jar commons-codec-1.5.
jar bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar poi-3.8.jar poi-scrat
chpad-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar xmlbeans-2.
3.0.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar tagsoup-
1.2.1.jar asm-3.1.jar isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar met
adata-extractor-2.4.0-beta-1.jar boilerpipe-1.1.0.jar rome-0.9.jar jd
om-1.0.jar vorbis-java-core-0.1.jar juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar pdfbo
x-1.7.1.jar fontbox-1.7.1.jar jempbox-1.7.1.jar commons-logging-1.1.1
.jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar tika-app-1.2.jar tika-xmp-1.2.jar xmpcore-5
.1.2.jar gson-1.7.1.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar slf4
j-api-1.6.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_271
Main-Class: com.vit.TikaSample

В настройках проекта прописывал свой main класс,
а также сделал это и в файле pom.xml.
Подскажите как быть? У кого есть какие-то идеи на этот счет?
Как решить подобную задачу, заранее спасибо.

Comment: скажите, вы что-то грузите из ресурсов? судя по  стектрейсу очень похоже... и еще, предоставьте полный текст ошибки, а не огрызок на скрине. по этому скриншоту точно сказать ничего нельзя

Comment: Судя по ошибке нехватает зависимостей. Добавьте опцию -сp tika-core-1.2.jar tika-parsers-1.2.jar vorbis-java-tika-0. 1.jar netcdf-4.2-min.jar apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar apache-mime4j-d om-0.7.2.jar commons-compress-1.4.1.jar xz-1.0.jar commons-codec-1.5. jar bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar poi-3.8.jar poi-scrat chpad-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-3.8.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar xmlbeans-2. 3.0.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar tagsoup- 1.2.1.jar asm-3.1.jar isoparser-1.0-RC-1.jar aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar met adata-extractor-2.4.0-beta-1.jar ...

Comment: На скриншоте из консоле весь текст ошибки, а не часть, как могло показаться. Подскажите что вы увидели по стектрейсу?

Comment: Подскажите как добавить такую опцию? Как новую секцию в pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение по следующей ветке - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven.

Мой новый jar файл начал запускаться после того, как я добавил maven-dependency-plugin в свой файл pom.xml. Этот плагин смог собрать все jar файлы, на которые я ссылаюсь в main классе, в одной папке lib, при этом сделав так, чтобы можно было их использовать из нее. Этот плагин должен быть перед maven-jar-plugin.

Если у вас похожая проблема, вам необходимо добавить в pom.xml этот код с этим плагином:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                   <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                   <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                   <mainClass>com.vit.TikaSample</mainClass>
                   
                   <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
               <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```